# index out of range exception at datareader value

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Property objproperty = new Property();
    objproperty.Username = txtusername.Text.Trim();
    objproperty.Password = txtpassword.Text.Trim();
    IDataReader rdr = objadd.login(objproperty);
    while(rdr.Read())
    {
        Session["Userid"] =rdr["UserId"].ToString();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        rdr.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: UserId

at rdr["UserId"] it showing the above error
    i am unable to solve this please help me

Comment: UserId is not exist rdr, so please check the Login function and see what result is returning

Comment: While loop is running more than one time?

Comment: @deepak-aggrawal
you are right!! i got it now

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revise your query in your Login function, and make sure you have the field "UserId" selected, if your selecting it, make sure its not aliased.